# How to get all instances of money from a string?

Tags: shared-libraries, currency

I want to get all the money instances present in a string. For example: for the input string - "I owe you $2,000 and I don't even have a dollar bill.", I want the output to be a list containing the money and its currency unit.
Output - [(2000, 'USD'),(1,'USD')]. I have tried writing a regex but I need to consider several cases which made the task complex as I have to account for other currency units as well and cases like "1 Million Dollars" and "Rs 1 lakh". Please suggest some libraries for this task. Any programming language will be appreciated.

Comment: You could take a look at [money-parser](https://pypi.org/project/money-parser/) (python).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that but I couldn't get the currency unit.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you can do this

```js
var rgx = /(\$|€|£|¥)(!?([-,._ ]?\d{1,3})*)/g;
var result = rgx.exec("$ -100.343.234.234,00");
console.log(result);
```